# Catch errors for NSNotification postNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

How to catch if `NSNotificationCenter` `postNotificationName` failed to post due to unfound observer or any other reason ?

- In my case, **sometimes** `postNotificationName` is called before observer was added so I want to handle such case

What i tried is some bad solution :

I made a global `NSArray`, When `postNotificationName` is executed, I insert notification details in that array, then empty that array when the observer actually receives the notification, I make a check later in other class to see if its empty, if not then `postNotificationName` had failed.

Answer (score 1):

That's really not how `NSNotificationCenter` is meant to work. It acts as a one-to-many way of distributing messages (`NSNotification`s) to other object that add themselves as listeners. Just because the notification was received by one listener, does not mean that it was received by all. And if no class is registered as a listener, the post did not "fail to post" it's just that no object was there to listen.

It sounds like what you're looking for is a queuing system. Forget the `NSNotificationCenter` and just use your `NSArray` as a queuing mechanism, or get more elaborate from there.

Comment: Is there any solid example of full queueing functionality

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure it'll work for you or not but you can remove the observer before adding.

I don't think there will be some easy way to check whether the notification really received by the observer or not. Apart from all of this your approach is right.